# Apache2 - .htaccess Redirect all to https://www

Tags: apache2

I need a htaccess rule that redirect all kind of page opening like http://oursite.com or http://www.oursite.com to `httpS://WWW.oursite.com`

Can you give me that kind of rule?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /page-404.php
RewriteEngine On

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule .+ - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s([^\s]+)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule .* %1.html [R=301,L]

# make sure .php file exists for the requested .html file
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ $1.php [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: anything you tried, including reading the documentation and / or manpage?

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple:

```
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</ifmodule>
```